# Uploading Image with PHP to .txt File

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to add an image upload field to my PHP contact form. I have **contact.html** which posts to **contact.php**. I write all data to a **errors.txt** file.

I want to be able to upload images and move it to an "upload" folder on the server while registering it in errors.txt file.

I have marked sections of upload with NOT WORKING comment. Please guide me.

**contact.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="contact.php"> 

<h1>Basic Info</h1>

Username: <input type="text" name="user">    
<br>Email: <input type="text" name="mail">
<option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option> <option value="advanced">Advanced</optio></select> 

    <!-- Image Upload Code - NOT WORKING -->
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

<br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['user'];

    $email = $_POST['mail'];

    $experience = $_POST['exp'];

    // IMAGE UPLOAD CODE - NOT WORKING

    $target_file = "uploads/" . basename ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);


    //the data

    $data = "$username | $email | $experience | $target_file\n";


    //open the file and choose the mode

    $fh = fopen("errors.txt", "a");

    fwrite($fh, $data);


    //close the file

    fclose($fh);


    print "User Submitted";
}
?>
```

Comment: `action="signup.php"` seems like submission goes to another script.

Comment: @TimothyHa - That was a type I made while posting it here. The original problem still persists.

Comment: you never bother checking if an upload actually occurred, or succeeded. Your FIRST check should be `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']`

Comment: I tried your code Its works very fine.. included <select> ??

Comment: How did you try it? I am using WAMP on local machine it gives errors. Also, fixed <select>.

Comment: i tried in godaddy server

Comment: Please, post the content of the error log file located in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your HTML is malformed! Missing open `<select>` tag ?

Which cause your input `type="file"` to be ignored by your browser.
Try this :

```html
Username: <input type="text" name="user">    
<br>Email: <input type="text" name="mail">
<select name=exp>
<option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
<option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
</select>
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not solve the problem - was ignored by the browser.

Comment: @Arsonik yes, I put it as shown above - between form tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your Upload folder name is upload or uploads ??.  In your query, you said "upload" folder.

```
     $target_file = "uploads/" . basename ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: It is Upload, @Indra. Thank you for your help ... I am listening.